# php newsletter script duplicating body content

Tags: php, newsletter

just done a little bit of code to send out a newsletter based on a sql table.

first one with 70/80 subscribers went off fine, now when i've moved to the second one that has around 250, the body_message of the email is repeated inside the email equally to the number of people on the mailing list, in this case I was sending emails with 250 duplicates of the content inside...

not sure whats wrong with the code, have stripped it down as much as i could and was wondering if someone could talk a look and hopefully point out the issue

```
    <?php

$i=1;
if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
connect_newsletter();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, mail FROM test") or die('Could not connect. ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $email = $row['mail'];
    $nid = $row['id'];

    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

    $ref="http://www.domain.co.uk";

    $body_message ='newsletter html code';

    $y_email="noreply@domain.co.uk";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers4=$y_email;       
    $headers .="Reply-to: $headers4\n";
    $headers .= "From: $headers4\n"; 
    $headers .= "Errors-to: $headers4\n"; 

    $subject="subject";

    mail($email,$subject,$body_message,$headers);


    echo $i." sent to ".$email; 
    echo "<br>";
    $i++;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching your code that is not possibile because in the loop you safely reset the value of `$body` and `$subject`

The problem could be somewhere else. Check your `sendmail log`

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me who cant see an issue, where would one generally find said log?

Comment: /var/log/maillog but it could vary based on your linux. Anyway you said your first 70-80 went fine and then the others no. Are you using another script for this others? Why they are splitted in two groups?

Comment: bummer, don't have access to that directory i believe. they are two different newsletters for different sites. the first 80 did go fine, and all i really did was copy and paste bits into the new script and fix up accordingly. I have proof read the hell out of them both though and cannot see anything

Comment: HMMM if you copy paste for the second group and the first group is working maybe you added some errors in the second script.

Comment: well it wasn't just a copy paste, i mainly just pulled the sql and if code accross. I have managed to get into mail.log and cannot see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: the situation is: if the first script works fine, and your second script does not probably it's because while you did your copy/paste you added some errors there.

Comment: Well i'll give them both another read through if nothing shows up based on the above code.

Comment: seems the previous script had the same problem, it was just un-noticed in comparison

Comment: @xand94. that changes everything. At this point i suggest you to try PHPMailer and not using mail() php function.

Comment: think i will give that a go yeah